# WebGL - get a static position for light

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple example with drawing a sphere. I have added two lights at position (x,y,z) = (0,100,0) and (0,-100,0) (i.e on south and north hemispheres). You can see the result on [this link](http://93.184.46.144/test/index.html)

I would like to prevent the lights to follow the mouse rotation, I have seen different methods with OpenGL but I wonder how to acheive it with WebGL.

Here the code snippet defining this 2 lights :

```
  // Lights for scene
  var lights = [];
  lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
  lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );

  lights[0].position.set( 0, 100, 0 );
  lights[1].position.set( 0, -100, 0 );

  scene.add( lights[0] );
  scene.add( lights[1] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the lights to the camera rather than the scene. This way the lights' position is relative to the camera's:

```
camera.add( lights[0] )
camera.add( lights[1] )
```

And ensure that you add the camera to the scene after adding the lights to it:

```
scene.add( camera )
```

Comment: it seems that lights disappears with your solution and the color of sphere is also modified. Are you sure this is the good solution ?

Comment: Did you add the camera to the scene after adding the lights to it? That could be the matter (as said in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740277/three-js-add-light-to-camera). (I updated the answer)